# Using Vue.js and Bootstrap, will I still need to use a Vue UI framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

While I am getting to know how use Vue to make  a property web site more dynamic  and I am currently using and happy with Bootstrap, there are few UI frameworks for Vue - most of them material.
My question is do I have to use one of these frameworks to make the most of Vue.js
or should I just stick to Bootstrap as  is  maintained and tested by hundreds of people.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the end you will build something like this https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/ if you choose second way - using bootstrap along with vue. I mean that you can start without any framework at all, but going vue-way you eventually will have a small collection of components that your application need. There is at least one viable reason to go that way - learning vue.

If you want bootstrap-look vue application and have enough knowledge of vue, check this lib - i think you will save some of your time by using already created vue-bootstrap components - and this is a main reason, in my opinion, to use any vue ui framework at start. Quote from frontpage:

> Build responsive, mobile-first projects on the web using Vue.js and
> the world's most popular front-end CSS library — Bootstrap V4
>
> **Bootstrap-Vue** provides one of the most comprehensive implementations
> of Bootstrap V4 components and grid system available for Vue.js 2.4+,
> complete with extensive and automated WAI-ARIA accessibility markup.

Comment: You are right, I ll be  using   and modifying the component I need  from bootstrap vue.  I don' t need material look and fancy look.